# If $z_{1},z_{2},z_{3},z_{4}$ are vertices of Rhombus, Then value of $z_{1}+\omega z_{2}+\omega^2 z_{3}=$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $ABCD$ are rhombus in argand plane, If the affix of the vertices's are $z_{1}\;,z_{2}\;,z_{3}\;,z_{4}$
>
> respectively and $\angle CBA = 60^0\;,$ Then value of $z_{1}+\omega z_{2}+\omega^2 z_{3}=?$
>
> Where $\omega$ is a Complex cube root of unity.

[image]

$\bf{My\; Try:}$ Using Rotation Theorem:: $\displaystyle \frac{z_{1}-z_{2}}{z_{3}-z_{2}}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}=\omega.$

So we get $z_{1}-z_{2}=\omega\left(z_{3}-z_{2}\right)\implies z_{1}-z_{2}=\omega z_{3}-\omega z_{2}\implies z_{1}-(1-\omega)z_{2}-\omega z_{3}=0$

I did not understand how can I solve it

Help Required, Thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that the triangles ABC and ADC are equilateral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First apply the rotation formula to obtain $z_3=z_1+e^{i\pi/3}(z_2-z_1)$

Now  just substitute this in the expression and keep on simplifying:
$$\begin{align}
z_1+\omega z_2+\omega ^2z_3&=z_1+\omega z_2+\omega ^2(z_1+e^{i\pi/3}(z_2-z_1))\\\
&=z_1+\omega z_2+\omega ^2z_1+\omega ^2e^{i\pi/3}(z_2-z_1)\\\
&=z_1+\omega z_2+\omega ^2z_1-\omega (z_2-z_1)\\\
&=z_1+\omega z_1+\omega ^2z_1\\\
&=z_1(1+\omega +\omega ^2)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It's also worth noting that one should not use find and replace to replace all the $w$s with $\omega$s.